# is_front_page not working correctly on WordPress

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I'm working on a wordpress project. I have few contents in header and sidebar that I want to display only on the main front-page of the website. I have a custom front-page.php as a front page template where I list posts from two categories using custom wp_query.

I have tried to put my conditional contents using `is_front_page` condition tag, but it doesn't seems to work, no clue why its not working?

Before, putting a custom front page template using front-page.php, it was working just nice, but after I implemented front page template it stops working.

Any clue how to fix this?

Comment: [This may help](http://nspeaks.com/difference-between-is_home-and-is_front_page/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with using query_posts. We changed that part, and it started to work again.

Actually query_posts rewrites original query and it causes conditional tags to break, as per wp codex.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check to see what your `Settings -> Reading : "Front Page Displays"` is set to?

If you're trying to place the conditional in the `sidebar.php` or the `header.php` it should work fine.

This may help clarify: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/if-is_front_page-not-working#post-1290807